# can you guide me how can ı solve this?

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-distribution

Missiles are launched until one successfully reaches the target. If the expected number of launches
is 2.5, find the probability that at most 3 attempts will be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this looks like a homework question, I'll give some hints instead of a complete solution. Assume independent and identical trials (o/w the question should provide more information).

- Let $X$ be defined as the number of trials until success, with success probability $p$. $X$ is a well-known RV, i.e. [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).
- You're given the expected value, which is $1/p$
- You have the PMF of the random variable in the wikipedia page. Find $p$ above, and substitute for probability of at most three attempts, i.e. $P(X\leq 3)=\sum_{i=1}^3 P(X=i)$

Comment: thank you sir , when ı used geometric formula  ı found (0.4 * 0.6 )+ (0.4 *0.6^2) +(0.4 *0.6^3)  = 0.47 but answer is  "0.784" what is the missing thing in my solution ?

Comment: for ex. $P(X=1)=0.4$ (note that 0.784 * 0.6 = 0.47)

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: $1-0.6^3=0.784$